# Error while creating Vector

Tags: polkadot, ink

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std, no_main)]

// use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
mod memory_game {
    use ink::{
        prelude::vec::Vec
    };
    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct MemoryGame {
        tiles: Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>,
        try_count: u32,
        best_count: u32,
    }

    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Copy)]
     #[ink::scale_derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo)]
    pub enum TileContent {
        Hearts,
        WaterDrop,
        DiceSixFacesFive,
        Umbrella,
        Cube,
        BeachBall,
        Dragonfly,
        Hummingbird,
        FlowerEmblem,
        OpenBook,
    }

    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Copy)]
    pub enum TileState {
        Start,
        Flipped,
        Matched,
    }

    impl MemoryGame {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            MemoryGame {
                tiles: Vec::new(),
                try_count: 0,
                best_count: 0,
            }
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get_tiles(&self, tile_count: u32) -> Vec<(TileContent, TileState)> {
            // Throw error if count is not even.
            assert!(tile_count % 2 == 0, "The number of tiles must be even.");

            // Use the existing list if it exists.
            if !self.tiles.is_empty() {
                return self.tiles.clone();
            }

            let pair_count = tile_count / 2;

            // Take only the items we need from the list of possibilities.
            let used_tile_contents = [
                TileContent::Hearts,
                TileContent::WaterDrop,
                TileContent::DiceSixFacesFive,
                TileContent::Umbrella,
                TileContent::Cube,
                TileContent::BeachBall,
                TileContent::Dragonfly,
                TileContent::Hummingbird,
                TileContent::FlowerEmblem,
                TileContent::OpenBook,
            ];

            // Double the array and shuffle it.
            // let mut rng = ink_env::hash::Sha2_256::default();
            let mut shuffled_contents = used_tile_contents
                .iter()
                .cycle()
                .take(pair_count as usize * 2)
                .copied()
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();
            // shuffled_contents.shuffle(&mut rng);

            self.tiles = shuffled_contents
                .into_iter()
                .map(|content| (content, TileState::Start))
                .collect();

            self.tiles.clone()
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn flip(&mut self, index: u32) {
            // Is the tile already flipped? We don’t allow flipping it back.
            if self.tiles[index as usize].1 == TileState::Flipped {
                return;
            }

            // How many tiles are currently flipped?
            let flipped_tiles = self
                .tiles
                .iter()
                .filter(|(_, state)| *state == TileState::Flipped)
                .count();

            // Don't allow more than 2 tiles to be flipped at once.
            if flipped_tiles == 2 {
                return;
            }

            // On the second flip, check if the tiles match.
            if flipped_tiles == 1 {
                self.try_count += 1;

                let already_flipped_tile = self
                    .tiles
                    .iter()
                    .find(|(_, state)| *state == TileState::Flipped)
                    .unwrap()
                    .0;
                let just_flipped_tile = self.tiles[index as usize].0;

                let new_state = if already_flipped_tile == just_flipped_tile {
                    TileState::Matched
                } else {
                    TileState::Start
                };

                // If all tiles are matched, the game is over.
                if self
                    .tiles
                    .iter()
                    .all(|(_, state)| *state == TileState::Matched)
                {
                    self.end();
                }

                self.tiles.iter_mut().for_each(|(_, state)| {
                    if *state == TileState::Flipped {
                        *state = new_state;
                    }
                });
            }

            self.tiles[index as usize].1 = TileState::Flipped;
        }

        fn end(&mut self) {
            // Your end logic goes here
        }
    }
}
```

while trying to deploy the ink smart contract i get this error,I don't have an idea how to fix it

```
12 |         tiles: Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>,
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ink::parity_scale_codec::Decode` is not implemented for `Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>`
   |
   = help: the trait `ink::parity_scale_codec::Decode` is implemented for `Vec<T>`
   = note: required for `Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>` to implement `Packed`
   = note: required for `Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>` to implement `StorableHint<()>`
   = note: required for `Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>` to implement `AutoStorableHint<ManualKey<760146325>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[(TileContent, TileState)]: Encode` is not satisfied
  --> \\?\C:\Users\Admin\Documents\mightymeld-memory\contracts\tastymatch\lib.rs:12:16
   |
12 |         tiles: Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>,
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Encode` is not implemented for `[(TileContent, TileState)]`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Encode`:
             [T; N]
             [T]
   = note: required for `Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>` to implement `Encode`
   = note: required for `Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>` to implement `Packed`
   = note: required for `Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>` to implement `StorableHint<()>`
   = note: required for `Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>` to implement `AutoStorableHint<ManualKey<760146325>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[(TileContent, TileState)]: Encode` is not satisfied
  --> \\?\C:\Users\Admin\Documents\mightymeld-memory\contracts\tastymatch\lib.rs:50:53
   |
50 |         pub fn get_tiles(&self, tile_count: u32) -> Vec<(TileContent, TileState)> {
   |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Encode` is not implemented for `[(TileContent, TileState)]`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Encode`:
             [T; N]
             [T]
   = note: required for `Vec<(TileContent, TileState)>` to implement `Encode`
note: required by a bound in `DispatchOutput`
  --> C:\Users\Admin\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\ink-5.0.0-rc.3\src\codegen\dispatch\type_check.rs:69:8
   |
67 | pub struct DispatchOutput<T>(T)
   |            -------------- required by a bound in this struct
68 | where
69 |     T: scale::Encode + 'static;
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `DispatchOutput`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't derive `Encode, Decode` for `TileState`

```rs
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Copy)]
#[ink::scale_derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo)]
pub enum TileState {
    Start,
    Flipped,
    Matched,
}
```

Comment: thank you solved